# How to perform the same edit on a folder of csv files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, log-ascii-standard

I have a folder of Log ASCII Standard (LAS) files that are comma delimited. Using the lasio package, I can read and edit them normally; however, I want to edit them so they become tab delimited and save as such in the folder.

I've already tried lasio's version editor, as version 2.0 would be tab dilimited:

```
las.write("file.las", version=2.0)
```

however, I get:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.str_' and
>   'numpy.str_'

every time. I've also tried changing the dtypes of the data to objects/float. I can't seem to be able to figure out what to do next.

Comment: Hi, I'm the maintainer of lasio - can you post the full TypeError exception traceback? It will give a clue as to where the error is being raised.